# DXL scrippting for find the enum in attributs

Tags: ibm-doors

How I can find a string in Doors attributes . e.g. 
I have doors attributes, which has values type of Enumeration
1. AA 2. BB 3. cc 4. dd

How I can find DXL script that in particular attributes , say it contains two AA, and 3 BB

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you mean with "two AA", in a multi value enumeration, an attribute either has AA set or not set, it cannot be set twice.
If you have a multi value enumeration with the allowed values "AA", "BB", "cc" and "dd", you can use the perm `bool isMember(attrRef, string)`.
Example from DXL manual:

```
if (isMember((current Object)."Country", "Australia")) {
    addRequirement("Right-hand drive model needed")
}
```